# Original url: hall/booking.php?hall_id=1&booking_date=2014-10-23&session=Morning I want: hall/booking/1/2014-10-23/Morning

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have one url in my project like

hall/description_banquethall.php?hall_id=1 and my url is working like hall/description_banquethall/1

by using this .htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /hall

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?id=123 to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?hall_id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/? [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo/12 to /dir/foo.php?id=12
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?hall_id=$2 [L,QSA]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

now i want to redirect my another url hall/booking.php?hall_id=1&booking_date=2014-10-23&session=Morning to hall/booking/1/2014-10-23/Morning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below `## hide .php extension snippet` line add these 2 new rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?hall_id=([^&\s]+)&booking_date=([^&\s]+)&session=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3/%4? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?hall_id=$2&booking_date=$3&session=$4 [L,QSA]
```